# carousel lwc component only width needs to increase

Tags: css, lwc

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-3">
    <lightning-carousel>
        <lightning-carousel-image
            src={companyLogoUrl}
            header="Company logo"
            description="Company logo uploaded to a static resource"
            alternative-text="Company logo">
        </lightning-carousel-image>
        <lightning-carousel-image
            src={product1Url}
            header="Fantastic product 1"
            description="Fantastic product image in a zip file"
            alternative-text="Fantastic product 1">
        </lightning-carousel-image>
        <lightning-carousel-image
            src={product2Url}
            header="Fantastic product 2"
            description="Fantastic product image in a zip file"
            alternative-text="Fantastic product 2">
        </lightning-carousel-image>
    </lightning-carousel>
    </div>
</template>
```

I created a carousel component and only width needs to increase.If i try to increase width using custom css or slds means the height also increasing and the component looking so big Any idea how to increase only width of the component.I tried slds-size_1-of-2 but it's height is also increasing

Answer (score 0):

The lightning-carousel will occupy all the width that the container lets him occupy. Your container is using `slds-size_1-of-3`, which means the container itself, will occupy a third of the parent container space. For instance, if you place it in a section on app builder, it will occupy a third of the width.

On top of that, the lightning-carousel images maintain the aspect ratio of the image height/width proportions. You won't be able to just change the image width.

My suggestion is that you remove the `slds-size_1-of-3` class, and if you want to modify the aspect ratio of your images edit them with an image edition program.